# ЧПУ в htaccess Не срабатывает строчка RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess

Не срабатывает строчка

```
RewriteRule ^nazvanie/$ contacty_nazvanie.php [QSA,L]
```

Или я не правильно понимаю. Как я читаю, в случае если пользователь перешёл по строчке `домен.ру/nazvanie`, ему отображают контент `домен.ру/contacty_nazvanie.php`

Почему-то не срабатывает, или я не верно понимаю

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^nazvanie/$ contacty_nazvanie.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Правило выше добавит ".php" и следующее правило уже не сработает

Comment: Правило выше убирает php наоборот

Comment: ну дак вы закомментируйте строку, да проверьте. или местами строки поменяйте.

Comment: "убирает" оно от пользователя. а в работе оно заменяет одно на другое, и это другое обрабатывается дальше.